# Help me choose a NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage

I'm looking for a NAS for a Windows system, I want the following features:

I want to synchronize files between my work and home computer both running Windows.

It should provide good security, other people should be able to get my files.

It should have good power consumption when not used.

It should be able to use some kind of RAID so I won't lose data if one hdd breaks down.

Good price :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can buy some hardware and install [Openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/) or [Freenas](http://freenas.org/) on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personnally a big fan of [QNAP](http://www.qnap.com) products. You're quite vague in your description, you should probably take a look at their extensive [features matrix](http://www.qnap.com/images/products/comparison/Comparison_NAS.html) to have an idea of what each product can do.

Comment: The QNap are the best of the current consumer grade NAS. The rest of the crowd fares from utterly terrible to barely functional.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand your third line, secure but others should be able to get your files?

You also don't mention storage volume requirements.

Either way nothing you've requested should be too hard to get and configure, pretty much anything should do - I like Thecus boxes as they're linux-based so very configurable but any NAS box when combined with correct router configuration will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

D-Link DNS 323, you can even install Debian GNU/Linux for armel on it!